Farting and breaking wudu
Let’s say you thought you farted, but then you changed your mind. Would your wudu still be valid, because if your not sure that you farted then it is broken. But if you changed your mind, will it still be gone because you first thought that you farted which broke it.

Alhamdulillah,
The general principle is that certainty cannot be overruled by doubt. If you are certain you had wudu, but then doubted whether something broke it (like a potential fart), that doubt alone does not invalidate your original state of certainty about having wudu.
The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said: "Whoever finds something in his stomach (like a wet dream or passing wind) and is doubtful about it, should not leave the mosque unless he hears a sound or notices a smell." (Bukhari, Muslim)
This hadith indicates that mere doubt about passing wind is not sufficient to break one's wudu. There needs to be certainty through hearing the sound or smelling the odor.
If you initially thought you passed wind, but then were no longer certain and had doubt, your wudu remains valid because the original state of having wudu remains until you are certain it was broken.
And Allah knows best!
